# Mesillat Yesharim Melody (Niggun)

Tags: song-poetry, mussar-ethics

Years ago I ran across a recording online of a niggun for reciting the opening paragraphs of Mesillat Yesharim. I can't relocate it, but I slightly remember reading that it was a well known learning niggun of a particular rabbi. Is anyone familiar with melodies for reciting Mesillat Yesharim?

Answer (score 3):

The tune [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrZHsOpJrPg) is the one we used to sing.

Comment: Which uses the tune of an Israeli kids' Chanukah song https://youtu.be/liAmCVeNvZE

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31174)

Comment: @sabbahillel How does this not answer the question?

Comment: You should give the details of the song and explain how it answers the question.

Comment: That is a nice melody Danny Schoemann. It's not the one that I am hoping to track down, but I might try using this one. The one I remember was more of a lernin niggun than a song.